# NGINX instance problems

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, cloud

[This is the screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OmBl.jpg)

I was creating an NGINX instance and while managing the instance group, I am facing this issue. The hint in the cloud says "Please create the managed instance group with 2 NGINX web servers". Stuck up from quite some time, What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

You can follow below steps to complete the task -

Create startup.sh file

```
#! /bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install -y nginx
service nginx start
sed -i -- 's/nginx/Google Cloud Platform - '"\$HOSTNAME"'/' /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html
EOF
```

1. Create an instance template

```
gcloud compute instance-templates create web-server-template \
--metadata-from-file startup-script=startup.sh \
--network nucleus-vpc \
--machine-type g1-small \
--region us-east1
```

2. Create a managed instance group

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed create web-server-group \
--base-instance-name web-server \
--size 2 \
--template web-server-template \
--region us-east1
```

3. Create a firewall rule to allow traffic (80/tcp)

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create web-server-firewall \
--allow tcp:80 \
--network nucleus-vpc
```

4. Create a health check

```
gcloud compute http-health-checks create http-basic-check
```

5. Create a backend service and attach the manged instance group

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed \
set-named-ports web-server-group \
--named-ports http:80 \
--region us-east1
```

6. Create a backend service and attach the manged instance group

```
gcloud compute backend-services create web-server-backend \
--protocol HTTP \
--http-health-checks http-basic-check \
--global
```

7. Create a URL map and target HTTP proxy to route requests to your URL map

```
gcloud compute backend-services add-backend web-server-backend \
--instance-group web-server-group \
--instance-group-region us-east1 \
--global

gcloud compute url-maps create web-server-map \
--default-service web-server-backend

gcloud compute target-http-proxies create http-lb-proxy \
--url-map web-server-map
```

8. Create a forwarding rule

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create http-content-rule \
--global \
--target-http-proxy http-lb-proxy \
--ports 80

gcloud compute forwarding-rules list
```

Wait for for extra 10 mins to Create the website behind the HTTP load balancer.

Comment: If problem still exist, goto google cloud console and create one more backend service inside web-server-template and assign HOST and path randomly

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use GCP Managed Instance Groups (MIG), and for that you are required to have an Instance Template from where the MIG is going to take the information in order to deploy.

Long story short, you are defining how large you want your resources to be, but you are not specifying what those resources are.

You can follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates) if you like but here's the short version of it:

```
gcloud compute instance-templates create nginx-template \
--machine-type e2-standard-4 \
--image-family debian-9 \
--image-project debian-cloud \
--boot-disk-size 250GB
```

Either that or the template you are using doesn't exist anymore since you are using qwiklabs and those projects get erased after a while.

Answer (score 0):

To the previous comment, I would only add that there is one extra line needed -

```
 gcloud container clusters create nucleus-jumphost-webserver1
```

Taken from here - https://gist.github.com/Tambunan26/9063521fdf406645aad4527ccd069149

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).